# Dot product of hdf5 array

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am making neural network whose input array is hdf5 array X and weight matrix is W1. I am trying to do dot product of these 2 as below and stroing it in other hdf5 array.

```
f = h5py.File('z2.hdf5')
self.f['z2'] = np.dot(X,self.W1)
```

But above line gives me MemoryError. How to solve it? How to perform dot product of hdf5 array?

Comment: Try to understand how big Your data is, and if it really does not fit into memory, try something like dask.pydata.org

Comment: It fits in memory. Problem is with np.dot() . It can not handle huge arrays. np.transpose(X) is also not working when X is very large in size of some GBs @kakk11

Comment: How large are the arrays, np.dot obviously creates a new matrix, thus asking for more memory...

Comment: It is about 1.2 GB and I am storing it by hdf5 array. It my expand. Now how do i compute its dot product with other matrix??  @kakk11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-overview.html

"""Dask Array implements a subset of the NumPy ndarray interface using blocked algorithms, cutting up the large array into many small arrays. This lets us compute on arrays larger than memory using all of our cores."""

And

"""
The dask.array library supports the following interface from numpy:

...

Tensor contractions / dot products / matrix multiply, `tensordot`"""

Working example for illustration, try different dimensions to see performance of numpy vs dask.

```
import dask as dk
import tables
import numpy as np
from time import time

outpath = "/tmp/"
lenx = 300
leny = 100000
fname = "t{0:03d}_{1:03d}.h5".format(int(lenx/100),int(leny/100))

def write_test_file():
    h5file = tables.open_file(outpath+fname,"w")
    pres = np.random.random((lenx,leny))
    atom = tables.Float64Atom()
    filters = tables.Filters(complevel=6, complib='zlib', shuffle=True)
    print("Writing data")
    t01 = time()
    h5file.create_carray(h5file.root,'pressure',atom,(lenx,leny),filters=filters,obj=pres)
    h5file.flush()
    del pres
    t02 = time()
    lines = np.random.random((leny,lenx))
    h5file.create_carray(h5file.root,"lines",atom,(leny,lenx),filters=filters,obj=lines)
    t03 = time()
    print("Data written",t03-t02,t02-t01)
    h5file.close()

def numpy_dot_test():
    print("Open data")
    t1 = time()
    h5open = tables.open_file(outpath+fname,mode="r")
    pressureObject = h5open.get_node("/", "pressure")
    print(pressureObject.shape)
    linesObject=h5open.get_node("/","lines")
    print(linesObject.shape)
    t2 = time()
    ohoo = np.array(linesObject).dot(np.array(pressureObject))
    t3 = time()
    print(ohoo.shape,np.mean(ohoo))
    print("matmul time:",t3-t2,t2-t1)
    h5open.close()

def dask_dot_test():
    import h5py
    import dask.array as da
    h5open2 = h5py.File(outpath+fname)
    t21=time()
    d1=da.from_array(h5open2["/pressure"],chunks=(100,lenx))
    d2=da.from_array(h5open2["/lines"],chunks=(leny,100))
    t22=time()
    print('d1,d2',d1.shape,d2.shape)
    d1.dot(d2).to_hdf5(outpath+'output.h5','testout')
    t23=time()
    print('ohoo',t23-t22,t22-t21)
    h5open2.close()


write_test_file()
    ## numpy_dot_test()
dask_dot_test()
```

Comment: Well I have my X of 1.2 GB and w to be like 7500 x 10 matrix. I am trying to do dot product i.e., f['z2'] = X.dot(w) and it has taken almost 1 hour and showed no result. What is problem here? Has computation time got anything to do with chunks? @kakk11

Comment: Yes, chunking is important. I added a working example of using dask, please see if it helps You, if not, please share more of Your code.

Comment: Well I am begineer and I am unknown to many functions in your example. But however I am stuck at "dask_array.compute()" . It is not working and it freezes shell and I am also unable to kill it. May I show u code?

Comment: Yes, You can show the code. One reason I know why the _compute_ command may hang is that it creates too many computing tasks first and then the compute graph drives it crazy. You can probably get rid of it by changing chunking.

Comment: I am getting memory error with dask_array.compute(). I have shared my code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283938/memory-error-with-dask-array). Your any advice or help will be appreciated

Comment: I had my process killed a couple of time with the code above; then I changed *chunks* parameter in d1,d2 definitions in *dask_dot_test* from 100 to 600 and it worked perfectly. Thanks!