# Memory error with dask array

Tags: python, arrays, out-of-memory, dask

I am implementing Neural Network whose input and output matrices are very large, so I am using dask arrays for storing them.

`X` is input matrix of 32000 x 7500 and `y` is output matrix of same dimension.

Below is neural network code having 1 hidden layer:

```
class Neural_Network(object):
    def __init__(self,i,j,k):
        #define hyperparameters
        self.inputLayerSize = i
        self.outputLayerSize = j
        self.hiddenLayerSize = k
        #weights
        self.W1 = da.random.normal(0.5,0.5,size =(self.inputLayerSize,self.hiddenLayerSize),chunks=(1000,1000))
        self.W2 = da.random.normal(0.5,0.5,size =(self.hiddenLayerSize,self.outputLayerSize),chunks=(1000,1000))
        self.W1 = self.W1.astype('float96')
        self.W2 = self.W2.astype('float96')

    def forward(self,X):
        self.z2 = X.dot(self.W1)
        self.a2 = self.z2.map_blocks(self.sigmoid)
        self.z3 = self.a2.dot(self.W2)
        yhat = self.z3.map_blocks(self.sigmoid)
        return yhat

    def exp(z):
        return np.exp(z)

    def sigmoid(self,z):
        #sigmoid function
##        return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
        return 1/(1+(-z).map_blocks(self.exp))

    def sigmoidprime(self,z):
        ez = (-z).map_blocks(self.exp)
        return ez/(1+ez**2)

    def costFunction (self,X,y):
        self.yHat = self.forward(X)
        return 1/2*sum((y-self.yHat)**2)

    def costFunctionPrime (self,X,y):
        self.yHat = self.forward(X)
        self.error = -(y - self.yHat)
        self.delta3 = self.error*self.z3.map_blocks(self.sigmoidprime)
        dJdW2 = self.a2.transpose().dot(self.delta3)
        self.delta2 = self.delta3.dot(self.W2.transpose())*self.z2.map_blocks(self.sigmoidprime)
        dJdW1 = X.transpose().dot(self.delta2)
        return dJdW1 , dJdW2
```

Now I try to reduce cost of function as below:

```
>>> n = Neural_Network(7420,7420,5000)
>>> for i in range(0,500):
    cost1,cost2 = n.costFunctionPrime(X,y)
    n.W1 = n.W1 -3*cost1
    n.W2 = n.W2 -3*cost2
    if i%5==0:
        print (i*100/500,'%')
```

But when `i` reaches around 120 it gives me error:

```
    File "<pyshell#127>", line 3, in <module>
    n.W1 = n.W1 -3*cost1
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py", line 1109, in __sub__
    return elemwise(operator.sub, self, other)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py", line 2132, in elemwise
    dtype=dt, name=name)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py", line 1659, in atop
    return Array(merge(dsk, *dsks), out, chunks, dtype=dtype)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\toolz\functoolz.py", line 219, in __call__
    return self._partial(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\toolz\curried\exceptions.py", line 20, in merge
    return toolz.merge(*dicts, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\toolz\dicttoolz.py", line 39, in merge
    rv.update(d)
MemoryError
```

It also gives `MemoryError` when I do `nn.W1.compute()`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like its failing while building the graph, not during computation.  Two things come to mind:

#### Avoid excessive looping

Each iteration of your for loop may be dumping millions of tasks into the task graph.  Each task probably takes up something like 100B to 1kB.  When these add up they can easily overwhelm your machine.

In a typical deep learning library, like Theano, you would use a `scan` operation for something like this.  Dask.array has no such operation.

#### Avoid inserting graphs into graphs

You call map_blocks on a function that itself calls map_blocks.

```
self.delta2 = self.delta3.dot(self.W2.transpose())*self.z2.map_blocks(self.sigmoidprime)

def sigmoidprime(self,z):
    ez = (-z).map_blocks(self.exp)
    return ez/(1+ez**2)
```

Instead you might just make a sigmoid prime function

```
def sigmoidprime(z):
    ez = np.exp(-z)
    return ez / (1 + ez ** 2)
```

And then map that function

```
self.z2.map_blocks(sigmoidprime)
```

#### Deep learning is tricky

Generally speaking, doing deep learning well often requires specialization.  The libraries designed to do this well generally aren't general purpose for a reason.  A general purpose library, like dask.array *might* be useful but will probably never reach the smooth operation of a library like Theano.

#### A possible approach

You might try building a function that takes just one step.  It would read from disk, do all of your dot products, transposes, and normal computations, and would then store explicitly into an on-disk dataset.  You would then call this function many times.  Even then I'm not convinced that the scheduling policies behind dask.array could do this well.

Comment: Can np.exp() handle large dask arrays? I tried doing np.exp(X) where X is 32000 x 7500 but it failed! Now what can I do?

Comment: It gives Memory Error.. Help

Comment: You shouldn't call `np.exp` on a dask.array.  Having it within a function that gets called by `map_blocks` is fine though.

Comment: So what can I do to avoid above error?? Pls suggest me a way out.. Help!!

Comment: I suggest that you try all of the recommendations above.  If they do not work for some reason then provide a detailed-yet-simple example of things failing and raise an issue.

Comment: Well I noticed that when python crosses about 950MB (from task manager) of memory it raises this issue. Will it stop throwing this error if I somehow increase memory usage specially for python?